# A well structured and good question should be prevented from being downvoted?

Tags: discussion, support, downvotes

I had a question about a functionality of JavaScript.

It is a well written, correctly formatted and grammatically correct question as suggested by one of the top users of Stack Overflow, **Jon skeet** in [this article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and I also showed my attempts to solve the problem, but some users keep downvoting the question when they were unable to help me solve the problem.

My question is this: Is this really the right approach? Because sometimes downvote on a good question discourages the user as well as other site visitors to ask more questions. It also reflects in the user profile and makes the user look amateur and can negatively impact his/her ability to ask more questions in future.

Is there a solution for situations like this?

Comment: Not being one of those users, I can't really say why they chose to do what they did; I can at least offer a hypothetical or two: The documentation for angularjs specifies that `ng-click` is for event handling, not triggering the event itself.  Reading the documentation would have solved that problem.  As to the research itself, I don't see any of that in your question.  I see your attempt, but not any research.

Comment: my tip for you (again and again): complaining down votes here (especially without valid reason and with bad attitude) would probably gain more down votes, know?

Comment: Your post is contradictory.  That your post is being downvoted means that *it's not a good question*.  If your question *was* a good question, it wouldn't have been downvoted.  When your post is being downvoted you should be asking yourself how you can improve the question such that it no longer merits downvotes, rather than blaming people for providing you (and others) valuable feedback as to the quality of your question.

Comment: Just so you know, complaining about downvotes on meta almost assuredly is going to earn you even more downvotes.

Answer (score 17):

The solution is to improve your question. It has a few problems.

## User Confusion

Your question drew many comments like these:

> but title of question is saying something else
>
> What are you trying to achieve? You want to trigger the "click" event when the condition becomes true? Or do you want to enable the "click" event in that case?
>
> what do yo mean by trigger the click event on condition true? do you mean trigger as in element.click() or do you want execute some method when the condition is true?
>
> does these anchor tags have a click handler bound else where? they are definitely not bound in angular, I suppose. Its really hard to solve the problem, when we dont understand the context.

Users are saying they think your question is unclear or doesn't make sense. That's an appropriate reason to downvote. From the downvote arrow mouseover text:

> This question does not show any research effort; **it is unclear** or not useful

(emphasis added)

## Volatile Commenting

In addition, I can see no less than 6 comments that you posted and then deleted. Many of the comments that you posted and then deleted were replies to other users. But you didn't wait until those users responded. They may never have seen your comments, leading to the impression that you were ignoring requests for clarification. That probably contributed to the confusion.

## Lack of Research

On top of that, as Daedalus [pointed out in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338078/a-well-structured-and-good-question-should-be-prevented-from-being-downvoted/338079#comment413261_338078) on this Meta post,

> The documentation for angularjs specifies that `ng-click` is for event handling, not triggering the event itself.

In other words, your question on the Main site doesn't really make sense. You are trying to trigger the event using the mechanism for *handling* the event. Users tend to downvote if a question doesn't show research. And, again, that's an appropriate reason to downvote.

## Now What?

What else can you do about it, other than try to improve it? Nothing. Now that it has upvoted answers, you can't delete it unilaterally. You can't make people not vote on it or change their votes if you disagree. ***The solution is to try to improve the question.***

Comment: I understand all your point but I am just saying that this question is still better than most questions posted on SO these days. I am a regular user of SO and know about the quality of questions. I was not here to get more downvotes to my original question.

Comment: One more thing, The documentation for angular JS specifies that ng-click is for event handling, not triggering the event itself. If I knew that why would I come to SO for an answer? Everything is written somewhere on the internet.I needed an solution urgently that's why I asked that question.

Comment: You say, "[T]his question is still better than most questions posted on SO these days." I don't really agree, but that doesn't matter. What matters is that the downvoters are telling you *they* don't agree. What you're running into now is the "Meta effect": you've attracted attention to your question, so now you're going to get more votes on it. If the trend was negative before, it's likely to continue that way, but with bigger numbers.

Comment: As for researching before posting on SO: you are expected to do at least a little research before posting. A question that is easily answered by glancing at the documentation is not likely to be well-received.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi Also, if you need a solution urgently, I'd recommend seeking help elsewhere; SO is not there for urgent needs.  Those that answer questions here are volunteers, except in the rare case that they're actually employed by SE.

Comment: Yeah ok. I will be more through with my questions from next time.Is it possible to delete my original angular js SO question by any means??

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi No, not unless you can convince a bunch of folks with the "delete" privilege to do it. We generally will not delete questions that folks have taken the time to contribute answers to. That would waste their time and effort.